# How do I write this member constraint in F#?

Tags: generics, f#

For a type

```
type Cow() =
    class
        member this.Walk () = Console.WriteLine("The cow walks.")
    end
```

I can write a method which enforces a member constrain for method Walk like

```
let inline walk_the_creature creature =  
    (^a : (member Walk : unit -> unit) creature)
// and then do
walk_the_creature (Cow())
```

In this case the type is inferred. I am unable to explicitly write a constraint on the creature parameter like this

```
// Does not compile
// Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this 
// program point. A type annotation may be needed...
let inline walk_the_creature_2 (creature:^a when ^a:(member Walk : unit -> unit)) =
    creature.Walk()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not explicitly writing the constraints that is the issue, it's that the syntax is not so nice that you can place a member constraint on a parameter and then invoke the member in the usual way. The body of `walk_the_creature` and `walk_the_creature2` would be the same here:

```
let inline walk_the_creature_2 (creature:^a when ^a:(member Walk : unit -> unit)) =
    (^a : (member Walk : unit -> unit) creature)
```

Comment: Could you explain why the body is required to be written in this manner. Isn't all the type information already present in the second method?

Comment: The member constraint system is quite complex and separate from the nominal type system, so you don't get nominal member invocation syntax for free. In fact, `(^a : (member Walk : unit -> unit) creature)` doesn't invoke anything, it is a template for generating an (inlined) type specific implementation of the function at compile time. I suppose the unified syntax desired could be implemented, but the F# team never anticipated member constraints becoming so popular, intending them only for core libraries, and hence the syntax is a total wreck in this version (crossing fingers).