# How this type annotation works, and why the other one does not?

Tags: f#

Please explain the magic behind `drawShape` function. 1) Why it works at all -- I mean how it calls the `Draw` member, 2) why it needs to be `inline`?

```
type Triangle() =
    member x.Draw() = printfn "Drawing triangle"

type Rectangle() =
    member x.Draw() = printfn "Drawing rectangle"

let inline drawShape (shape : ^a) =
    (^a : (member Draw : unit->unit) shape)

let triangle = Triangle()
let rect = Rectangle()

drawShape triangle
drawShape rect
```

And the next issue is -- is it possible to write `drawShape` function using parameter type annotation like below? I found that it has exactly the same signature as the first one, but I'm unable to complete the body.

```
let inline drawShape2 (shape : ^a when ^a : (member Draw : unit->unit)) =
    ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the magic is all in the F# compiler - don't know what more to say - for your second issue: without seeing the body/error you have it's quite hard to tell

Comment: I tried just put `shape.Draw()` in the body without success. The error is: `error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.`

Comment: ah I see - well sadly you have to repeat the same thing you did in `drawShap` yet again (the part inside the `(^a : (member Draw : ...) shape)`

Comment: just a comment on this: *IMHO* you should really only use this *feature* when you absolutely have to - here it would be much easier to have a `IDrawable` interface with the abstract `Draw` method instead.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid -- OO inspired explicit interfaces. ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This Voodoo-looking syntax is called "[statically resolved type parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx)". The idea is to ask the compiler to check that the type passed as generic argument has certain members on it (in your example - `Draw`).

Since CLR does not support such checks, they have to be done at compile time, which the F# compiler is happy to do for you, but it also comes with a price: because there is no CLR support, there is no way to compile such function to IL, which means that it has to be "duplicated" every time it's used with a new generic argument (this technique is also sometimes known as "[monomorphisation](http://mlton.org/Monomorphise)"), and that's what the `inline` keyword is for.

As for the calling syntax: for some reason, just declaring the constraint on the parameter itself doesn't cut it. You need to declare it every time you actually *reference* the member:

```
// Error: "x" is unknown
let inline f (a: ^a when ^a: (member x: unit -> string)) = a.x() 

// Compiles fine
let inline f a = (^a: (member x: unit -> string)( a )) 

// Have to jump through the same hoop for every call
let inline f (a: ^a) (b: ^a) = 
  let x = (^a: (member x: unit -> string)( a ))
  let y = (^a: (member x: unit -> string)( b ))
  x+y

// But can wrap it up if it becomes too messy
let inline f (a: ^a) (b: ^a) = 
  let callX t = (^a: (member x: unit -> string) t)
  (callX a) + (callX b)

// This constraint also implicitly carries over to anybody calling your function:
> let inline g x y = (f x y) + (f y x)
val inline g : x: ^a -> y: ^a -> string when  ^a : (member x :  ^a -> string)

// But only if those functions are also inline:
> let g x y = (f x y) + (f y x)
Script.fsx(49,14): error FS0332: Could not resolve the ambiguity inherent in the use of the operator 'x' at or near this program point. Consider using type annotations to resolve the ambiguity.
```

Comment: Thank you for great explanation and the links. So, concluding, this `(^a: (member x: unit -> string)( a ))` roughly means "make sure that type `^a` contains member `x` which is a parameterless function returning string, and call it on instance `a` with no arguments.

Comment: regarding member constraints see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694633/how-do-i-write-this-member-constraint-in-f