# Why does F# infer int in this function?

Tags: f#, type-inference

In F# I can combine strings with the `+` operator as follows:

```
let myString = "one" + "two"
```

But when I create a function that will accept two arguments and apply the same operator, and I put it in a module declared ahead of its usage, F# infers the types as integers:

```
module StringFunctions = 

let add str1 str2 = 
    str1 + str2
```

Calling the below gives me the build error, "The expressions was expected to have type 'int' but here has type 'string'":

`let str3 = StringFunctions.add "three" "four"`

Why does F# infer this as int? I assume that it can't be a generic method because not all types will implement the `+` operator, but why does it assume int?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3754961/2314532 will go a long way towards answering your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# generics / function overloading syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445828/f-generics-function-overloading-syntax)

Comment: I don't think this question is a precise duplicate of [F# generics / function overloading syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445828/f-generics-function-overloading-syntax), though it's pretty close. So I've given a short answer; read the linked question(s) for more detailed explanations.

Comment: @spmdc - I think rmunn's answer is far more succinct and useful for someone new to F#. The question you reference is a leap too far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short version is, "Because that's how F# is designed".

The longer version is that if a function's type can't be generic (and you're correct that this one can't since not all types will necessarily inplement the `+` operator), then F# has to pick a real type. The most common use case for the `+` operator is adding integers, so F# defaults to assuming that `+` is the integer-addition operator unless you tell it otherwise.

One way you could tell it otherwise is to put in a type annotation:

```
let add (str1 : string) str2 = str1 + str2
```

Note that you don't have to annotate both parameters: knowing that one side of the `+` operator is a string is enough to let F# infer that the other side must be a string as well.

The other thing you could do is to make the function `inline`, which will result in two things:

1. F# will not compile this into a function call, but will actually *insert* the function's code into the calling locations, and
2. Because of this, the F# compiler will be able to use *different* `+` operators in different calling locations, if needed.

That is, `add 3 5` would become `3 + 5` which uses the integer-addition operator, and `add "foo" "bar"` would become `"foo" + "bar"` which uses the string-addition overload of `+`.

The reasons why this works are gone into in more depth in questions like [F# generics / function overloading syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445828/f-generics-function-overloading-syntax) and [Use of `inline` in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754862/use-of-inline-in-f/) (among others), so I won't get into them here.